# Cisco 7921G IP Phone not working

Tags: cisco, voip

Got my hands on a second hand 7921G wireless IP phone. It should be configurable via USB; but need drivers to do that (http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/voice_ip_comm/cuipph/7921g/5_0_1/english/administration/guide/7921cfgu.html#wp1333330).

The drivers seem to be available at http://www.cisco.com/cgi-bin/tablebuild.pl/ip-7900ser-crypto, but I don't have an account there. Is there any other way to configure the phone?

Comment: Just register, it costs nothing.

Comment: I did - drivers still out of reach. I'm not a cisco reseller or partner :(

Comment: This is reason #2514 to not purchase used Cisco gear unless you are willing to fork out for their software as well.